# Ember multiple sendAction failing

Tags: javascript, ember.js

**Update below**

Here's an interesting one. I have a template which contains a form component, and that form component's template also includes a component:

```
NewObj.hbs -> obj-form.js / obj-form.hbs -> file-uploader.js
```

The file uploader uses `ember-uploader` and it works great. I used its events to make `sendAction` calls to tell the obj-form controller that things are happening, IE pass on the upload progress percentage and indicate when the upload is complete.

If however I add one more `sendAction`, for some reason obj-form never receives the event for `onComplete`. No matter how I try it, it just never happens - no errors anywhere.

The `file-uploader` component is invoked in the obj-form template like so:

```
{{file-uploader
      url="/uploads"
      onProgress="fileUploadProgress"
      onComplete="fileUploadComplete"
      value=newProjectDownloadFile}}
```

`file-uploader.js` itself looks like this:

```
App.FileUploaderComponent = EmberUploader.FileField.extend({
  url: '',

  onProgress: 'onProgress',
  onComplete: 'onComplete',

  filesDidChange: function(files) {
    var uploadUrl = this.get('url');
    var that = this;
    var uploader = EmberUploader.Uploader.create({
      url: uploadUrl
    });

    uploader.on('progress', function (e) {
      that.sendAction('onProgress', e);
    });

    uploader.on('didUpload', function (response) {
      that.sendAction('onComplete', response);
    });
    if (!Ember.isEmpty(files)) {
      uploader.upload(files[0]);
    }
  }

});
```

And `obj-form.js` has these methods in the actions hash:

```
fileUploadProgress: function (e) {
    this.set('uploadPercentage', e.percent.toFixed(2));
},
fileUploadComplete: function (response) {
  this.set('newProjectDownloadFileUrl', response.url);
  this.set('newProjectDownloadFileName', response.fileName);
  this.send('addDownload');
},
```

It works great. But I wanted to make a progress bar only appear while uploading and disappear when upload was complete. I added the property `uploadInProgress`: false to the `obj-form` controller, and this:

```
isUploading: function () {
  return this.uploadInProgress;
}.property('this.uploadInProgress')
```

I use `{{#if isUploading}}` to show/hide the progress bar.

I added:

```
 this.set('uploadInProgress', false);
```

to the `obj-form` `fileUploadComplete()` method, and added this new method:

```
fileUploadStart: function () {
  this.set('uploadInProgress', true);
},
```

I modified the `file-uploader` component call to this:

```
{{file-uploader
      url="/connect/projectDownloads/file"
      onStart="fileUploadStart"
      onProgress="fileUploadProgress"
      onComplete="fileUploadComplete"
      value=newProjectDownloadFile}}
```

And changed `file-uploader.js` to look like this:

```
App.FileUploaderComponent = EmberUploader.FileField.extend({
  url: '',

  onStart: 'onStart',
  onProgress: 'onProgress',
  onComplete: 'onComplete',

  filesDidChange: function(files) {
    var uploadUrl = this.get('url');
    var that = this;
    var uploader = EmberUploader.Uploader.create({
      url: uploadUrl
    });

    uploader.on('progress', function (e) {
      that.sendAction('onProgress', e);
    });

    uploader.on('didUpload', function (response) {
      that.sendAction('onComplete', response);
    });
    if (!Ember.isEmpty(files)) {
      that.sendAction('onStart', true);
      uploader.upload(files[0]);
    }
  }

});
```

I've tried putting the `that.sendAction('onStart', true);` bit in all kinds of places in `file-uploader.js` but if that line exists, then the `obj-form` controller never receives the `onComplete` action. I have absolutely no idea why. I take that line out, it works again.

**UPDATE** ok I've found something new. It's not the sendAction that breaks it, it's this line in obj-form.js:

```
this.set('uploadInProgress', true);
```

For some reason, when I set that to true, it all falls apart. I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong with the way I'm trying to make that work?

Could it be something to do with didInsertElement? I noticed that's getting triggered when I set uploadInProgress to true - because that property is being used to determine whether the progress bar appears on the page or not. So maybe I'm using didInsertElement incorrectly? Here's my didInsertElement and willDestroyElement:

```
   didInsertElement: function() {
   // console.log('didInsertElement');

   this.set( 'postType', this.get( 'content' ).get( 'postType' ) );
   this.set( 'projectDownloads', this.get( 'content' ).get( 'projectDownloads' ) );
   this.set( 'projectLinks', this.get( 'content' ).get( 'projectLinks' ) );
   this.set( 'published', this.get( 'content' ).get( 'published' ) );
   Ember.addObserver( this.get( 'content' ), 'postType', this, this.postTypeDidChange );
   Ember.addObserver( this.get( 'content' ), 'projectDownloads', this, this.projectDownloadsDidChange );
   Ember.addObserver( this.get( 'content' ), 'projectLinks', this, this.projectLinksDidChange );
   Ember.addObserver( this.get( 'content' ), 'published', this, this.publishedDidChange );
 },

  willDestroyElement: function() {
    console.log('willDestroyElement');
    Ember.removeObserver( this.get( 'content' ), 'postType', this.postTypeDidChange );
    Ember.removeObserver( this.get( 'content' ), 'projectDownloads', this.projectDownloadsDidChange );
    Ember.removeObserver( this.get( 'content' ), 'projectLinks', this.projectLinksDidChange );
    Ember.removeObserver( this.get( 'content' ), 'published', this.publishedDidChange );
  }
```

---

I've tried modifying isUploading to the alias style you recommended, but that hasn't helped anything. The idea is when that gets set to true, it makes the progress bar appear and the fileupload form disappear. Then when it gets set to false the reverse happens. I'm open to other ways to make this happen in Ember, I just can't figure out what I'm doing that's breaking things.

Comment: Does the `didUpload` callback get called?

Comment: Yep didUpload on file-uploader.js gets called but the fileUploadComplete on obj-form.js doesn't receive the action.

Answer (score 1):

Not the answer yet, but won't fit in comment correctly...  `this` isn't necessary in the dependency chain, even easier is to change this to an alias.

From

```
isUploading: function () {
  return this.uploadInProgress;
}.property('this.uploadInProgress')
```

To

```
isUploading: Ember.computed.alias('uploadInProgress')
```